# Android: lost project files just have key and apk

Tags: java, android, key, apk, restore

I wrote a little app just for a very small group of people over three years ago. Because I have currently enough free time I decided to add a Feature, but I am just able able to find the apk, the key and some icon files(stored on my server). I have changed computer twice, and most likley it got lost somewhere. It would no Problem to complete rewrite the app, but is it possible to recover the app from the apk and my key?

Answer (score 0):

For the most parts of your project the answer is yes. You can decompile your apk to retrieve the java code. This link should be useful:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1910873

I don't know if you can recover the xml-Files like the manifest from the apk.

Comment: Regarding the latter: you can, using `apktool`.